# Isn't "You can only post once every 40 minutes" a new user restriction?

Tags: discussion, question-restrictions

I posted a [tag-cleanup-request](/questions/tagged/tag-cleanup-request) on Super User (after discovering the broad [clock](/questions/tagged/clock) tag), then proceeded to ask my original question.

However, I got this error.

[image: You can only post once every 40 minutes.]

I have more then enough rep to get past the new user restrictions.

[image: 86 rep]

Is this a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), or is the posting limit not a new user restriction?

Comment: Duplicate says "Users with < 125 rep, 40 minutes since their last question anywhere on the network (This applies to the user's IP address, not their account. If the user shares that IP with other users, they can be limited by the other user asking a question anywhere on the network.)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty much all of the basic rate limits like that go away once you reach 125 reputation, not with the "remove new user restrictions" privilege you gain at 10 reputation.